# Is earning from making this site halal?

Tags: halal-haram, money, work

I created an introductory website for a shipping company. I knew that they only shipped halal things but later I came to know (after creating site) that they also ship few haram things (mostly ship halal things). Now is the money earned from making the site halal for me?

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly say "haram or halal", but it is clear according to the Quran 5:2

> وَلَا تَعَاوَنُوا۟ عَلَى ٱلْإِثْمِ وَٱلْعُدْوَٰنِ ۚ وَٱتَّقُوا۟ ٱللَّهَ ۖ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ شَدِيدُ ٱلْعِقَابِ ٢.....

> And do not cooperate in sin and transgression.
> And be mindful of Allah. Surely Allah is severe in punishment.

We should not help one another in sin and transgression. The site you have created helps them to sell haram things.

In your case you were assure that they are only selling halal items *" I knew that they only shipped halal things but later found out that they also sell haram things"*, *I advice you to always reassure things*.

**If you got the money after knowing that the website sells haram items then surely it was against the orders of Allah.**

Comment: better to ask this question on sites like [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en) or [Islam Q&A Fiqh](https://islamqa.org)